# Pandas : Reorganization of a DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-cleaning

I'm looking for a way to clean the following data:

[image]

I would like to output something like this:

[image]

with the tokenized words in the first column and their associated labels on the other.

Is there a particular strategy with Pandas and NLTK to obtain this type of output in one go?

Thank you in advance for your help or advice

Comment: Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57122617/2901002) solution, not accepted answer below or in dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the 1st table, it's simply a matter of **splitting the first column and repeating the 2nd column:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['foo bar', 'O'], ['George B', 'PERSON'], ['President', 'TITLE']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1', 'col2'])

print(df1)

df2 = pd.concat([pd.Series(row['col2'], row['col1'].split(' '))
                 for _, row in df1.iterrows()]).reset_index()
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'index': 'col1', 0: 'col2'})
print(df2)
```

The output:

```
        col1    col2
0    foo bar       O
1   George B  PERSON
2  President   TITLE

        col1    col2
0        foo       O
1        bar       O
2     George  PERSON
3          B  PERSON
4  President   TITLE
```

**As for splitting the 1st column**, you want to look at the split method which supports regular expression, which should allow you to handle the various language delimiters:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html

**If 1st table is not given there is no way to do this in 1 go with pandas** since pandas has no built-in NLP capabilities.

Comment: Ya, unfortunately accepted answer not always means the best answer like this solution copied from dupe :(